# No Ethernet after hibernation

Tags: networking

I have quite a big problem. I did this:

1. I have Win 7 for quite a long time
2. I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 as dual boot with Win 7
3. First day (also during installation) wired internet was running.
4. I have tried to hibernate Ubuntu -> Laptop was turned off
   5) I turned on Laptop next day. From dual boot menu I have picked Ubuntu but there was a
   prob.. just black screen
5. I have done hard reset
6. From that point ethernet (wired internet) is not running. In Ubuntu I have following error:
   SIOCSIFADDR: No such device eth0
   eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

I have no idea what to do and I cannot understand how can this effect both systems. If you have any also small hints let me know, I'm desperate.. Thx

Answer (score 5):

*From the original author*

Ok [these guys](http://adeelejaz.com/blog/realteks-network-controller-deep-sleep-mode-issue/) had the solution. The network adapter was in deep sleep, so I had to unplugged the power cable and took out battery which resets the motherboard - and the network device.

*Not really much of a solution, however that seems to have fixed it for the author*